# Zend - form doesn't get validated

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm trying to validate a form in the actual form itself, but it doesn't get validated at all. If I type "someemail&*!([]@gmail.com", it doesn't really give a crap and moves on.
Form:

```
class RecoverPasswordForm extends Form {
    public function __construct($options = null) {
        parent::__construct("RecoverPassword");

        $username = new Element("username");
        $username->setLabel("Email");
        $username->setAttributes(
            array('filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name' => 'StripTags')),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Regex',
                        'options' => array(
                            'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/',
                            'messages' => array(
                                Regex::NOT_MATCH => 'The email your provided has invalid characters.',
                            ),
                        ),
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => "Email address is invalid",
                                EmailAddress::INVALID => "",
                                EmailAddress::INVALID_LOCAL_PART => "",
                                EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME => "",
                                EmailAddress::INVALID_SEGMENT => "",
                                EmailAddress::DOT_ATOM => "",
                                EmailAddress::INVALID_MX_RECORD => "",
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'label' => 'Email'));
        $this->add(array(
            $username,

        ));
    }
}
```

How I'm getting (or trying to get) the filters and validators in the controller:

```
      public function recoverPasswordAction() {
        $this->cache = new Container("cache");
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form = new RecoverPasswordForm();
//      $form->get("submit")->setValue("Send mail");
        $this->view->form = $form;
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $user = new User();
            $form->getInputFilter()->getValues();
            $form->setInputFilter($form->getInputFilter());
            $data = $request->getPost();
            $form->setData($data);
            $username = $data['username'];
            $userData = $this->getServiceLocator()->get("UserTable")->fetchList("`username` LIKE '$username'");
            if (!count($userData) > 0) {
                $this->cache->error = "A user with this email does not exist, plese try again.";
            }
                if ($form->isValid()) {
                    foreach ($userData as $user) {
                        $user->sendMail(6);
                        $this->cache->success = "A message has been send to this email, containing your password.";
                    }
                }
        }
        return $this->view;
    }
```

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't validate it

Comment: Whether you call $form->isValid() before calling $form->getInputFilter()->getValues(); ?

Comment: @MarcinTwardowski Updated my post with the controller code

Comment: It is no necessary to GET/SET inputFilter, try removing it, and a tip, do not query against DB before getting form validation, you are exposed to SQL Injection. First ask whether your form is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
$request = $this->getRequest();

$form = new Form();

if($request->isPost()) {
    if($form->isValid($reguest->getPost())) {
        $values = $form->getValues(); //filtered valid array of values

        $username = $form->getValue('username');


    }
}
$this->view->form = $form;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of wrong implementation of validators.

Could you try to implement `InputProviderInterface` on your form? Basic example is given in the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements). There it is set on an Element, but you can do this on your form too. This interface define `getInputSpecification` where you have to return an array with filter and validator specification.